# How to develop a project based on GitHub project?

Tags: angularjs, git, github

I would like to start develop Angular application based on `angular seed project` from Github. I don't know how to solve some scenarios.

I have existing project under `Git` with backend part and I would like to integrate Angular.

The project structure:

```
|
- backend/
- frontend(angular-seed-project)/
    |
    -app/
    -other files
```

How to retain `angular-seed-project` up to date, pull all bug fixes from angular seed project along with development own angular application.

Can I have different `git config url` in root of `angular-seed-project` and different url in `app/` folder?
Or is it better scenario to make initial pull to my git project and then fix bugs manually?

Comment: Do you plan on contributing back to the GitHub project you mentioned?

Comment: Seed projects usually are not meant to be contained completely within a folder. Usually, the seed project turns into *your* project, so you gradually replace everything to your needs.